# How to restrict access to Google Compute instance based on Google Authentication

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-authentication

I have a cloud instance which I would like to restrict access to. I'm wondering what's the right way to do it.

The setup:
1. I've opened a Google Compute cloud access and it has an external IP a.b.c.d
2. I would like everyone to be accessing a.b.c.d to be automatically redirected to google authentication, and if the account meets the policy, they will be able to proceed

Can anyone suggest a proper way of doing that? without adding code to the application running in a.b.c.d, but by configuring cloud instance

Comment: Are you trying to protect access via Google Cloud Console / APIs (control / manage the instance) or protect a web server endpoint and require user authentication to access content?

Answer (score 0):

Look into using the IAP (Internet Aware Proxy)... it can now be used to shield ssh requests.  I've not done what you're trying, but I think it is what you're looking for.